# Carousel with custom animation like Android 6 list of run apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, icarousel

How to achieve iCarousel acting like Android 6 list of run apps?

The best I could do is:

```
- (CATransform3D)carousel:(__unused iCarousel *)carousel itemTransformForOffset:(CGFloat)offset baseTransform:(CATransform3D)transform
{
      return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, 0.0f, offset * self.carousel.itemWidth);
}
```

Comment: A visual of what it looks like on Android could be interesting, and also what results give your code.

Comment: Here is Android 6 list - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3z78DTtM_53elB0ZlBDMndJUTg

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a nice look with a perspective like shuffling the cards:

```
- (CATransform3D)carousel:(__unused iCarousel *)carousel itemTransformForOffset:(CGFloat)offset baseTransform:(CATransform3D)transform
{
    transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, 1.0f + offset / 30.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, offset * 20.0f, offset);
}
```

A couple of tweaks here:

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(__unused iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
    switch (option)
    {
        case iCarouselOptionWrap:
        {
            return YES;
         }
        case iCarouselOptionSpacing:
       {

        return value * 1.5f;
        }
    case iCarouselOptionShowBackfaces:
    case iCarouselOptionRadius:
    case iCarouselOptionAngle:
    case iCarouselOptionArc:
    case iCarouselOptionTilt:
    case iCarouselOptionCount:
    {
        return value;
    }
    case iCarouselOptionFadeMax:
    {
        return value;
    }
    case iCarouselOptionFadeMin:
    {
        return 1.0f;
    }
    case iCarouselOptionFadeMinAlpha:
    {
        return 0.5f;
    }
    case iCarouselOptionFadeRange:
    {
        return value;
    }
    case iCarouselOptionOffsetMultiplier:
    {
        return 3.0f;
    }
    case iCarouselOptionVisibleItems:
    {
        return 3.0f;
    }
  }
}
```